# Find prev element source

Tags: jquery

I know this code below doesn't work, but is it possible with a call to get the `"src"` from the prev, `<img>`with a little tweak to the jquery below?

HTML:

```
<li>
    <img src="assets/themes/abstract/1_tbn.png" class="theme_tbn" />
    <label class="theme_label">Diffuse green</label>
    <span>
        <button class="btn-publish chooseTheme">Choose Theme</button>
    </span>
</li>
```

Jquery:

```
$(".chooseTheme").click(function () {        
    var src = $(".chooseTheme").find("img");
    alert(src.text());
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$(".chooseTheme").click(function () {        
        var src = $(this).closest('li').find("img").attr('src');
        alert(src);
});
```

Comment: Thanks! Worked like a charm! ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".chooseTheme").click(function () {        
    var src = $("li").find("img").attr('src');
    alert(src);
```

});